# How to find and replace words in a python file?

Tags: python

There is a template file:

```
ZOYX:_sName_:IUA:S:BCSU,_sNumb_:AFAST;

ZOYP:IUA:_sName_:"_ip1_",,49155:"_ip2_",30,,,49155;

ZDWP:_sName_:BCSU,_sNumb_:0,3:_sName_;

ZOYS:IUA:_sName_:ACT;

ZERC:BTS=58,TRX=_tNumb_::FREQ=567,TSC=0,:DNAME=_sName_:CH0=TCHD,CH1=TCHD,CH2=TCHD,CH3=TCHD,CH4=TCHD,CH5=TCHD,CH6=TCHD,CH7=TCHD:;

ZERM:BTS=58,TRX=_tNumb_:LEV=-91;

ZERM:BTS=58,TRX=_tNumb_:PREF=N;

ZERS:BTS=58,TRX=_tNumb_:U;`
```

In it, you need to replace *tNumb*, *sName*, *sNumb*, _ ip1_, *ip2*, with the values that the user enters.
That's how I did it:

`

```
repeat="y"
while repeat == "y":

    keys=['_ip1_', '_ip2_', '_sName_', '_sNumb_', '_tNumb_']
    print(keys) 
    #print(keys[2])
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++1")

    values=[]
    #ip1, ip2, sName, sNumb, tNumb = input("Enter the IP address1: "), input("Enter the IP address2: "), input("Enter the station name: "), input("Enter the station number: "), input("Enter the transmitter number: ")
    ip1, ip2, sName, sNumb, tNumb = 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555
    
    values.append(ip1)
    values.append(ip2)
    values.append(sName)
    values.append(sNumb)
    values.append(tNumb)
    print(values)
    #print(values[2])
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++2")

    dictionary={}
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        dictionary[keys[i]] = values[i]
        search_text = dictionary[keys[i]]
        replace_text = keys[i]
        print(search_text)
        print(replace_text)
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++3")


    with open(r'template.txt', 'r') as oFile:
        rFile = oFile.read()
    #print(rFile)
    with open(r'output.txt', 'a') as wFile:
        wFile.write('\n')
        wFile.write('\n')
        wFile.write('\n')
        wFile.write(rFile)





    repeat = input("Do you want to continue? (y/n): ")
    if repeat == "n":
        break
    while (repeat!="y" and repeat!="n"):
        repeat = input("Please enter the correct answer (y/n): ")
```

`
I have only a repeat of the text displayed in the output file. how do I find and change to the right words?

I have only a repeat of the text displayed in the output file. how do I find and change to the right words? I expected to get this in the output file:

```
ZOYX:33333:IUA:S:BCSU,55555:AFAST;

ZOYP:IUA:33333:"1111",,49155:"2222",30,,,49155;

ZDWP:33333:BCSU,55555:0,3:33333;

ZOYS:IUA:33333:ACT;

ZERC:BTS=58,TRX=3::FREQ=567,TSC=0,:DNAME=33333:CH0=TCHD,CH1=TCHD,CH2=TCHD,CH3=TCHD,CH4=TCHD,CH5=TCHD,CH6=TCHD,CH7=TCHD:;

ZERM:BTS=58,TRX=4444:LEV=-91;

ZERM:BTS=58,TRX=4444:PREF=N;

ZERS:BTS=58,TRX=4444:U;
```

Comment: Please read [mre] and show a simple example that directly demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You're reading the file and then not doing anything to it. You need to search the text for the tokens and replace them.

Comment: if you want to replace the file you need to open it in mode "w", not mode "a". are there any restrictions on modules you're allowed to use? re.sub() could be useful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Python code you have just read text from template.txt file and append it to output.txt file.
Just add below code replace key in keys list with user inputs.

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    rFile = rFile.replace(key, str(value))
```

Also, in line `keys=['_ip1_', '_ip2_', '_sName_', '_sNumb_', '_tNumb_']` '_' is added before and after each key. Please make sure that the keys in this list exactly match the text in the Template.txt file that you want to replace.